# Include external projects when releasing an open source iOS app + static lib?

Tags: ios, open-source, xcode4

I'm planning on releasing an open-source iOS static lib and sample app that depends on a number of third-party projects (OpenSSL, SQLCipher, FMDB, CHDataStructures and GHUnit).

Currently, I have all of the component projects building from source in a single XCode4 workspace. It was a *major* headache to get all of the build and dependency settings working properly.

I could release *just* my static lib and app, and provide a (likely very large) list of instructions and screenshots, but I know this will be error prone and frustrating to get working.

My inclination is to simply include *everything* in one Git repository (*which is how I'm currently working on the code privately*), but I understand this is not commonly done. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a directory structure in your repository so that it's reasonably obvious where folks are supposed to copy the version of each they have downloaded.  You could put a readme file that lists each dependency and a URL for it.

Something like:

```
/mikes-library-project
  /mikes-library-src
  /mikes-library-dependencies
    /openssl
    /sqlcipher
    /fmdb
    /chdatastructures
    /ghunit
```

mikes-library-project would be where your git repository is.  .gitignore would mask out mikes-libarary-dependencies so they would not be part of the repo.  You would include a readme-dependencies.txt in the mikes-libarary-project directory to list the version of each dependency you tested with and a URL to download the code.